# Flutter Auto Horizontal Scrollable Tags in loop

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

In my Application I want to create a Horizontal List Which has 2 widgets say Widget1 and Widget2. I want to keep them **auto scroll horizontally after every second**. But Condition is that in list second item in list should be visible 10%.

See Image

[image]

I have tried `viewportFraction` property `PageView.builder()`  but It also show previous item. But I want to so some part of next item only.

Comment: post your `PageView.builder(...)` code then

Comment: @pskink , I don't have code I tired with PageView but no success I also tied ListView, ListWheelView etc. I just want to achieve above thing in my app.

Comment: then you should use `PageView.builder` - the docs say: *"A scrollable list that works page by page.

Each child of a page view is forced to be the same size as the viewport."*

Comment: But Using View Pager how can I show preview on next item only (not Previous)

Comment: I Checked PageController reqired 3 fields initialPage, keepPage and viewportFraction. How can I achive Above using these fields.

Comment: you need `nextPage` method

Comment: thank you solved on one problem (moving from one page to another ), Even I can implement auto scroll with timer. But my main problem is that how can I show some part of Second page  (Say 10% only) If my First page is visible (say first page is current page).

Answer (score 0):

Hi After facing this issue I have Searched more and found a solution. It may help other's who may face same issue.

```
class TagScrollWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TagScrollWidgetState createState() => _TagScrollWidgetState();
}

class _TagScrollWidgetState extends State<TagScrollWidget> {
  final double imageIconSize = 25;
  double screenWidth;
  Timer timer;
  int currentIndex = 1;

  final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // To handle AutoScroll
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 3), (time) {
        scrollController.animateTo(
            currentIndex * (screenWidth - (15 + imageIconSize + 40)),
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            curve: Curves.easeIn);
        currentIndex++;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    timer?.cancel();
    scrollController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    // return only 2 data model for first and second item
    List<AutoScrollModel> repeatedList = Utils.getTagList();
    return Container(
      height: 40,
      child: ListView.builder(
          controller: scrollController,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            // Here you can return your own items repeat based on index 
            return _buildRow(repeatedList[index % 2]);
          }),
    );
  }

  // Build Your item
  Widget _buildRow(AutoScrollModel model) {
    return Container(
      // Note : this will show 80% of first Item and 20% of next item, Other wise
      // first item will take whole viewport
      width: screenWidth - (15 + imageIconSize + 40),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: 15,
          ),
          Image(
            image: AssetImage(model.leftImage),
            height: imageIconSize,
            width: imageIconSize,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 15,
          ),
          Text(
            model.message,
            maxLines: 2,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: AppFontSize.SMALL),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Important Points:

- Offest in animatTo Method must be index *widthOfItem
- To repeat item calculate reminder as index%numOfitems. now use reminder to show your item.
- Width of item must be 80% of screen width so that next item be visible 20%
- don't forget to dispose scrollController and cancel you timer.
- To stop Manual Scroll You can use NerverScrollPhysics in ListView.builder()

Thanks to pskink for comments in My Question.